# How to select two tables and combined them together if null isn't present

Tags: mysql

Currently I can search two tables (`events` table and the `users` table) and combined them together using the following:

```sql
SELECT e.*, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name
FROM users u, events e
WHERE e.event_user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY e.event_id DESC
```

This will allow me to search everything from the events table and the first and last name from the users table.

But the problem occurs when the `event_user_id` can be `NULL`, meaning if there is a user set, I want to include their first and last name, but if there isn't then I just want that field to be blank.

```sql
SELECT e.*, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name
FROM users u, events e
WHERE e.event_user_id = u.user_id
OR e.event_user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY e.event_id DESC
```

I know the above example isn't correct. **My question is**, how can I select two tables where the main table has an optional `event_user_id`, if it is not `NULL`, then combine with the `users` table to get the first and last name?

Is it just more reliable to have two separate queries?

Comment: `left join` and avoid comma-style joins ever.

Comment: mysql and sql-server are two different database engines, you should only tag the one you are using.

Comment: select e.*, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name
from users u
left join events e on u.user_id = e.event_user_id
order by e.event_id desc;

Comment: @Kateract Sorry, it's MySQL, accidentally tagged the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ivan mentioned in the comments to my question, the correct way to successfully carry out the query I want is to use a `left join`, so I did a bit of research and I found the right query for me:

```
SELECT events.*, users.user_first_name, users.user_last_name
FROM events
LEFT OUTER JOIN users
ON events.event_user_id = users.user_id;
```

If `event_user_id` is present, then the `user_first_name` and `user_last_name` will be added to the row, however, if `event_user_id` is `NULL` then both the first and last name will also be `NULL`. Exactly what I wanted.